# How to remove unnecessary files from /boot

Tags: boot, kernel

I wanted to upgrade my Ubuntu 18.04 but could not do that because there is not enough space available in /boot.

The content of /boot is:

```
System.map-4.15.0-173-generic
System.map-4.15.0-204-generic
System.map-4.15.0-29-generic
abi-4.15.0-29-generic
config-4.15.0-173-generic
config-4.15.0-204-generic
config-4.15.0-29-generic
grub
initrd.img-4.15.0-204-generic
lost+found
retpoline-4.15.0-29-generic
vmlinuz-4.15.0-173-generic
vmlinuz-4.15.0-204-generic
vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
```

Following [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) I did `sudo apt purge -y linux-{image,headers}-VERSION for all VERSIONs other than the one loaded.

This indeed removed all those version, the command `dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}'` shows:

```
linux-headers-4.15.0-204
linux-headers-4.15.0-204-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-204-generic
```

However, it did NOT remove any files from /boot - so the accepted answers for this problem did not work at all for me. Are there any alternatives?

UPDATE: the output of `apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-'[g|h|m|i]'` is

```
linux-generic
linux-headers-generic
```

Is it possible und safe to simple `sudo rm ...` the files that belong to unneded versions?

UPDATE: I started with trying `sudo apt autoremove --purge` which did not do anything at all.

UPDATE: output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-'[g|h|i|m|e]' | cut -d ' ' -f 3` is

```
binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu
linux-generic
linux-headers-4.15.0-204
linux-headers-4.15.0-204-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-204-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-173-generic
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-29-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-173-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-204-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-204-generic
```

UPDATE: output of `for f in /boot/* ; do  dpkg -S $f ; done | grep -v 204-generic | cut -f 1 -d ":"` is :

```
linux-modules-4.15.0-173-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-173-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic
linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-173-generic
linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-29-generic
```

Removing them all with `for f in /boot/* ; do  dpkg -S $f ; done | grep -v 204-generic | cut -f 1 -d ":" | xargs -n 1 sudo apt purge -y`:

This indeed removed all the unnecessary files in /boot - thank you @user535733 who shared the relevant idea in the comments!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143047/discussion-on-question-by-jpp1-how-to-remove-unnecessary-files-from-boot); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on the suggestion of user @user535733: remove all the packages whic still relate to the files in /boot, except those which contain the currect version string:

```
cur=`uname -r`
`for f in /boot/* ; do  dpkg -S $f ; done | grep -v $cur | cut -f 1 -d ":" | xargs -n 1 sudo apt purge -y`
```

Comment: Not sure I do not "speak"  bash, but should it not be `cur='uname -r'` ?

Comment: Thanks I inserted the missing space. The quotes do indeed need to be backquotes though.

Comment: This is a harsh solution. In my system it would remove memtest86+ package

Comment: @jarno - thank you for pointing this out, it could of course get prevented by filtering out anything one wants to keep using additional grep -v filters.
In my case, removing it was not only not a problem, but actually necessary to free enough space to make the subsequent upgrade work.

Comment: Oh, I checked that memtest86+ occupies less than 1% compared to what a kernel occupies in /boot. I doubt that upgrade would have failed for that.